# Sending Gujarati text to MySQL from Android using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing a sample app which has two textboxes that takes input from users. Now I have created a Gujarati keyboard using buttons so that user enters data in Gujarati language. When user presses Save button the data should be stored in MySQL. This is my complete code:

```
public void saveMy(View v)
{
    name=e1.getText().toString();
    no=e2.getText().toString();
    try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/GujaratiApp/myPHP.php");


            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",name));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("No",no));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+ex.toString());
    }   


}
```

And my PHP file is:

```
<?php 

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db("newDB");

  $name =   $_POST['Name'];

  $no = $_POST['No'] ;

  print("Name is:   ".$name."             And No is:".$no);

  $query_add="INSERT INTO  myData (`name` ,`no` ) VALUES ('$name','$no')";

  $query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Query used to create database is:

```
CREATE TABLE myData (name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,no VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET= utf-8;
```

My data gets enter when I press Save button but in MySql i get ??? instead of Gujarati text.

when I enter English data then it works properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little change in your code.
Try this.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters,HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to set charchter encoding on your PHP script:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

so put the above line of code in your php script.

Comment: make sure that "Collation" in your Database structure
set to "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: are u sure rayy on the the collation type?

Comment: Yes.. I changed server connection collation to "utf8_general_ci". Table has the same collation.

Comment: i am sure that the character encoding utf-8 must be for gujrati language.so try this on php script
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
put this code to the top of the script means below <?php